# Find beta from gamma distribution by inspection

Tags: self-study, gamma-distribution, beta-distribution

I'm doing exercises in order to prepare for an exam, and have the following question:

If Y has a probability density function given by

> f(y) = 4$y^2$$e^-$$^2$$^y$, y > 0 and 0 elsewhere.

obtain E(Y) and V(Y) by inspection.

My issue is with finding beta. Alpha I simply read as the exponent of $y^2$, where $\alpha = 2+1 = 3$.

To find beta, we look at the exponent of $e^-$, which is $y/$$\beta$. To not change the expression of $2y/$$\beta$, I'd say $\beta=1$. But in the coursebook they say that $\beta=0.5$, why is this? Wouldn't that alter the expression?

Comment: $y/\beta = 2y$ then $\beta = 1/2$

Comment: A think you should also add a self-study tag

Comment: Thank you, I can see why it's like that now. :) I add the tag also.

Comment: @BruceET I formulated the question precisely as it was formulated in my textbook. If you read my question you see that I knew that you look at the exponent of $e$ to find beta. It was rather this particular case that I didn't understand at first. I can't see what you're actually trying to say/provide with your comment?

Comment: Sorry if my Comment (now deleted) was not helpful. There have been at least two versions of your question. Even from the current version of your question,  it is not entirely clear to me what kind of help you are seeking.